# why only 1 checkbox values of array inserted into table

Tags: php, checkbox

i have manage to insert my checkbox array data into database. the problem is  when i check multiple checkbox only the first data in array is inserted in database. i need when i check  multiple checkbox, all the data i have check insert into database.can someone help me? Pleasee!

### php code 1:

```
 <?php
  include ('connect.php');

   $sql = "SELECT cat_id,name,gender,health_status,neutered,breed,color,age FROM cat WHERE owner_fk = '$id'";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
  $cato = $row6['cat_id'];
  $result = $conn-> query($sql);

 if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
 while ($row6 = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

    //table code//

   echo "<td>" ."<input type='checkbox'  name= 'check[]' value='$cato'". "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
   echo "</table>";
}
 else{
 echo "0 result";
}
  $conn-> close();

 ?>
```

### php code 2 :

```
<?php

 include ('connect.php');

$cat = implode(',', $_POST['check']);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

for($i=0; $i<count($cat);$i++)
{
    $p_id =$_GET ['sitter'];
    $price = $_POST ['price'];
    $pickup_date =$_POST ['pickup_date'];
    $dropoff_date =$_POST ['dropoff_date'];
    $numdays = $_POST ['numdays'];
    $total =$_POST ['test'];

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO cat_sitter(sitter_fk,cat_fk, price, date_in, date_out,total_day, total)VALUES ('$p_id','" . $cat[$i] . "','$price','$pickup_date','$dropoff_date','$numdays', '$total')" or die ("Error inserting data into table");

    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Succesfully Book.')
            window.location.replace(\"book_page.php\");
        </script>";
    }else{

        echo "error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }
     }
   }
 ?>
```

i really need insert all the data i checked insert into database.

Comment: the output of implode is a string, dont implode use the $_POST['check'] array

Comment: serialize the array while inserting and unserialize when you have to retrieve the data.

Answer (score -1):

Your php code 2 is correct, however, the problem lies in your checkboxes

```
while ($row6 = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<td>" ."<input type='checkbox'  name= 'check[]' value='$cato'". "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Your checkboxes here contains same value all throughout, maybe you're supposed to do `value="$row6["data"]` something like that?

Comment: his approach is correct, you can't insert an ARRAY in a database, you need to convert it into string first that is separated by comma then when you'll retrieve it, you will explode it again

Comment: no, he's treating the string `$cat` as an  array here: `$cat[$i]` he should be using  `$_POST['check'][$i]`

Comment: i tried still cannot insert multiple value in my db